# Blur background of form in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

### My code so far

I know my CSS code is not really good if you have suggestions to make it better tell me please.

```css
.login-dark form {
  max-width: 320px;
  width: 90%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  padding: 40px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.login-dark .illustration {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0 20px;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: #2980ef;
}

.login-dark form .form-control {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #434a52;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.login-dark form .btn-primary {
  background: #214a80;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 11px;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin-top: 26px;
  text-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}

.login-dark form .btn-primary:hover,
.login-dark form .btn-primary:active {
  background: #214a80;
  outline: none;
}

.login-dark form .forgot {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #6f7a85;
  opacity: 0.9;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.login-dark form .forgot:hover,
.login-dark form .forgot:active {
  opacity: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.login-dark form .btn-primary:active {
  transform: translateY(1px);
}

.blur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  position: absolute;
  width: 320px;
  height: 424px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div id="particles-js">
    <div class="blur"></div>
    <div class="login-dark">

      <form method="post">
        <h2 class="sr-only">Login Form</h2>
        <div class="illustration"><i class="icon ion-ios-locked-outline"></i></div>
        <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"></div>
        <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"></div>
        <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Log In</button></div><a class="forgot" href="#">Forgot your email or password?</a></form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="particles.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

I need to get the background of form blurry but I dont get how. Used Bootstrap and for the Background particle.js.

Trying since 5h but it won't work hope anyone of you can help me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Add this line to table

```
backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.login-dark form {
    max-width: 320px;
    width: 90%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding: 40px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 }
.login-dark .illustration {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0 20px;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: #2980ef;
}

.login-dark form .form-control {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 15px 0 5px 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
}
 input::placeholder{
  color:#FFF;
 }
.login-dark form .btn-primary {
  background: #FFF;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 11px;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin-top: 26px;
  text-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}
.login-dark form .btn-primary:hover, .login-dark form .btn-primary:active {
  background: #214a80;
  outline: none;
}
.login-dark form .forgot {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: 0.9;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.login-dark form .forgot:hover, .login-dark form .forgot:active {
  opacity: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.login-dark form .btn-primary:active {
  transform: translateY(1px);
}
.blur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  position: absolute;
  width: 320px;
  height: 424px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div id="particles-js">
    <div class="blur"></div>
    <div class="login-dark">

        <form method="post">
            <h2 class="sr-only">Login Form</h2>
            <div class="illustration"><i class="icon ion-ios-locked-outline"></i></div>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"></div>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"></div>
            <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Log In</button></div><a class="forgot" href="#">Forgot your email or password?</a></form>
    </div>
</div>
    <script src="particles.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks you for answering. Tried code but only thing changed that button is white when I dont hover.